# ElasticSearch: Selective query

Tags: elasticsearch

Needed some help.
My documents have a version field. Only updated documents will have a new record with an incremented version number.

Example:

```
{id:1 , version:1,…} 
{id:1 , version:2,….} //This has been updated
{id:2 , version:1,…}
```

In the above example id=1 has two records as it has been updated. While id=2 has a single record as it hasn’t been updated and is still sitting on version 1.

Now in elastic search are there any queries that can get a maximum version.
Example: Get unique documents TILL version 1 should give results:

```
{id:1 , version:1,…}
{id:2 , version:1,…}
```

While get unique documents till version 2 should give:

```
{id:1 , version:2,….}
{id:2 , version:1,…}
```

(in the above result there is a mix of version 1 and version 2)

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve this in elasticsearch (at least until something like [Field Collapsing/Combining](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256) is implemented). I would suggest maintaing two indices: one for all versions with auto-generated ids and another index with only the latest version with the record's `id` field as an id. When you need all versions, you can search the first index, when you need only the latest version, you can search the second.

An alternative solution is to somehow indicate that a record represents the latest version. It can be done by adding a boolean field "latest", which means that you will have to reindex the record with the previous latest version when a new record is added or you can add  a child document that will track the latest version for every record.

Comment: Hi Imotov, Thanks alot for replying.

Comment: Hi Imotov, Thanks alot for replying.I am trying to implement versioning in my Mongo Database. I am also trying to avoid duplication of data. Thus only updated documents will have a new version. In my above example id=1 has two records(version 1 and version 2) as it has been updated. While id=2 is still on version 1 as it was never updated. I have done this handling via the mongo-driver and then using the elasticsearch-mongo-river. Now my issue is that i need to selectively extract a version. Again if a document was not updated in version 2 then i should get its version1.